# How to connect to a Minecraft server with a custom client?

Tags: c#, minecraft, tcpclient

I'm developing a custom client in Unity C#. It is designed to be network-compatible with servers running Minecraft 1.8.8 (there is no server version for 1.8.9), Protocol version 47 (I think...)

According to https://wiki.vg/How_to_Write_a_Client#Login

> send a 0x02, get a 0xFD, send a 0xCD, get a 0x01, get a 0x06. Then you'll eventually get a 0x0D

So I send a 0x02...

```
void Connect() {
    tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    //TODO: will change IP and Port to modifiable values
    tcpClient.Connect("localhost", 25565); //Connects to server
    NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    print("TCP Connection Initialised");
    byte[] THEbyte = {0x02};
    ns.Write(THEbyte, 0, THEbyte.Length);
    THEbyte = Recieve(ns);
    print(THEbyte[0].ToString());
}

static byte[] Recieve(NetworkStream netstr) {
    try
    {
        byte[] recv = new Byte[256];

        int bytes = netstr.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length); //(**This receives the data using the byte method**)
        return recv;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);

        return null;
    }
}
```

I expect a 0xFD, but I get a 0 instead. Am I doing something wrong? Is it something wrong with how I'm interpreting the data that comes in, or is it an issue with sending? Is the guide only applicable to 1.16.5, and not the older version I am targeting?

Comment: see this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-5.0

Comment: It is very odd that you don't return `bytes`. The buffer **cannot** be correctly interpreted without that value - that is how many bytes were actually read. Everything else in the buffer is garbage and *should not be examined*. Is it possible that you're looking at this data when you see the unexpected value? One potential way of encapsulating this is to return an `ArraySegment<byte>` that describes the array *and* the length - or in more recent runtimes: `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` or `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`

Comment: I've tried returning `bytes` instead. It still is interpreted as 0. Do I need to return both `recv` and `bytes`?